# Truncate query issue in AWS Redshift

Tags: database, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

I am facing an issue with truncate query in Amazon redshift ra3.4xlarge cluster. It is taking very long time to complete truncate query on small tables. I have checked locks, server load and everything is fine. Still it is taking around 1 to 2 hrs to complete the query. Could you please help if anyone has an idea on this why it is taking more time Or any other blockers may impacting it?

Comment: That shouldn't be the case. Something has to be blocking it. If you make a brand new table and truncate it, is it still taking 2 hours?

Comment: How did you check locks?  Redshift has many types of locks and truncate commits all actions of the transaction it is running within.  There are a number of ways that locks are still getting in the way.  AWSLabs has some good SQL for looking into locks such as https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/blob/master/src/AdminViews/v_check_transaction_locks.sql

Comment: Thank you dfundako for your response. We tested it by creating new table using CTAS it was completed quickly but we don't have all the records in the table when we tested it

Comment: Thank you for your response Bill Weiner, I'm checking svv_locks and pg_locks table. Thank you for the SQL. I will use the same and check it.

Comment: Combobulator has a page which shows locks, and another which shows queries which are blocked by locks held by other queries.

https://www.redshiftresearchproject.org/combobulator/index.html

https://www.redshiftresearchproject.org/combobulator/docs/database_locks_v1.html

https://www.redshiftresearchproject.org/combobulator/docs/database_locks_blocked_v1.html